Powershell - Job injecting "System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob" in subsequent & call
I try to have a task being run, using a Job
The task waits fine but later on, as I run another process some weird string is getting injected
Here I ask user confirmation and run the task
function Get-BinariesPath()
{
    $result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Confirm","Confirm",'YesNo','Error')
    if ($result -eq "Yes") {
        $workingDirectory = $PWD.Path
        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            param ($dir)
            Push-Location -Path $dir
            cmd /c "cd $dir && some command to execute"
            Pop-Location
        } -ArgumentList $workingDirectory
        $null = Wait-Job $job
        #$output = $job | Receive-Job $job 
        $output = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemove
        #Get-Job | Remove-Job
        Remove-Job -Job $job
        $job = $null
    }
    ...
    $SomePathVariable = "Some/Command/Path/"
    return $SomePathVariable
}

Later on, in the calling script, this command is executed
$SomePathVariable = Get-BinariesPath
& "$SomePathVariable"

It looks the function returns $job and $SomePathVariable instead of just $SomePathVariable
System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob Some/Command/Path/ is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 

Whis the $job object returned by the function ?
Ho can I get rid of this ?
Why is the job interfereing with subseauent & ?
Thanks for your help

You need to add code that we can reproduce because as of now your question isn't clear

the function containing the Start-Job returns the $job object for some reason, while I return a $Path. this is not the 1st time I notice PS is giving we such issues

update this line: $output = Receive-Job $job to $output = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemove

I tried Get-Job | Remove-Job
Remove-Job -Job $job
$job = $null, same issue

Wait-Job $job is producing output from your function. Do $null = Wait-Job $job or use  $output = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemove as suggested before.

maybe with | Out-Null, but idk what line is causing the output

I updated my code above, nothing works

What is $output used for later on in this function? Again, you're missing an example we can use to reproduce this error otherwise it is all guessing.

I finally made it work, see my answer

and it does not work anymore, $output = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemove


        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Errors in packages.config projects:String) [], RemoteException




After fiddling, I found that this works
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ....
$null = Wait-Job $job | Out-Null
$output = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemove | Out-Null
$job = $null | Out-Null

note I had to restart the PS editor many times since it does not always take the modifications (VS Code or integrated PS editor)
